# Using Chrome to build a packet sniffer

Tags: google-chrome

Considering Chrome has a [network stack](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack), would it be possible to build a network sniffer in (or out of) the browser and get traces at IP, TCP or HTTP layers?

And if that is possible, where should I start?
(I have no knowledge of Chrome code)

Comment: HTTP, for sure: there's the HTTP monitor in the developer tools.

Comment: @Luis Yes, but if the page gets forwarded for example I lose the trace.

Comment: well, you wanted to know where you could start looking   :-D